# Function returns random value - guarantee they're different each time

Tags: python

I have a function to return random keys/values from a dict.

```
def heroes():
    hero, attribute = random.choice(list(heroes.items()))
    return(hero, attribute)
```

I call on this function several times throughout my app, I'm looking for a way to guarantee that each call returns a different random value than the previous one, is that possible to do easily?

Comment: If it is random there is no guarantee that the current one doesn't equal the previous one. But you can remove the item you are returning.

Comment: If the values _must_ be different each time, with zero probability of them being equal, you'll have to keep track of all the values ever returned by the function and check whether the newly created set has already been generated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that takes a dictionary and creates a random iterator for it:

```
import random

def rand_items(d):
    def g():
        d_items = list(d.items())
        random.shuffle(d_items)
        for i in d_items:
            yield i
    return g()

#tested like:

hero = {'batman':'rope','spiderman':'web', 'superman':'cape'}

heroes = rand_items(hero)

for h in heroes:
    print(h)
```

One run:

```
('spiderman', 'web')
('superman', 'cape')
('batman', 'rope')
```

You can get heroes one at a time. Initialize with:

```
heroes = rand_items(hero)
```

Then whenever you need a hero just use `next(heroes)` in place of your function call.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer to use a decorator. It allows you to loop infinitely through heroes. For example:

```
import random

# In this version heroes are global
HEROES = {'a':10, 'b':20, 'c':30, 'd':40}

def except_last_one(hero_func):
    # storage for the last hero
    last_hero = [None]
    def new_hero():
        # define a new hero (but not the last hero)
        last_hero[0] = hero_func([k for k in HEROES.keys() if k != last_hero[0]])[0]
        return (last_hero[0], HEROES[last_hero[0]])
    return new_hero

@except_last_one
def hero(heroes=HEROES.keys()):
    hero = random.choice(heroes)
    return (hero, HEROES[hero])
```

If you comment `@except_last_one` you obtain function equals to your function `heroes()`. And I'd maybe add an exception to catch a case when you have just one hero:

```
        try:
            last_hero[0] = hero_func([k for k in HEROES.keys() if k != last_hero[0]])[0]
        except IndexError:
            print 'Sorry, no heroes for you.'
            return (None, None)
```